# Django ORM, filtering objects by type with model inheritence

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have two models...

Parent and Child.

Child extends Parent.

When I do

Parent.objects.all(), I get both the Parents and the Children.

I only want Parents

Is there a Parent.objects.filter() argument I can use to only get the Parent objects instead of the objects that extend parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's a good place to use an **A**bstract **B**ase **C**lass instead of using inheritance. The ABC hold all the fields that are common to your classes. So, in your case, you will have one ABC mostly defined has your current Parent Class and 2 classes that will inherit from the ABC, that correspond to your Parent and Child classes.

```
class ABC(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ....

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Parent(ABC):
    ....

class Child(ABC):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

Check here for more info : [Model inheritance and Abstract base classes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#id5)

Comment: My pleasure!, But if you think it's the right answer, made it your accepted answer (click the check mark). Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

I've found a better way to solve this, using the django ORM and without the need for any changes to your models (such as an ABC):

> ```
> class Parent(models.Model):
>     field1 = models.IntegerField()
>     field2 = models.IntegerField()
>
> class Child(Parent):
>     field3 = models.IntegerField()
>
> #Return all Parent objects that aren't also Child objects:
> Parent.objects.filter(child=None)
> ```

This will result in the following query(conceptual, actual query may vary):

> SELECT "ap_parent"."field1","ap_parent"."field2" FROM "ap_parent" INNER
> JOIN "ap_child" ON
> ("parent"."parent_ptr_id" =
> "ap_child"."parent_ptr_id") WHERE
> "ap_child"."parent_ptr_id" IS NULL

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that inheritance is the right solution here? What about this?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.IntegerField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True)
```

Then you can query for all objects that are parents like this:

```
parents = MyModel.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)
children = MyModel.objects.filter(parent__isnull=False)
```

@Alex: filtering according to type won't work. Django's inheritance model isn't really that rich. E.g. with these models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class Child(Parent):
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

you get this behavior:

```
In [1]: from myexample.models import Parent, Child

In [2]: p = Parent(foo='x')

In [3]: p.save()

In [4]: p2 = Parent(foo='y')

In [5]: p2.save()

In [6]: c1 = Child(bar='1', foo='a')

In [7]: c1.save()

In [8]: c2 = Child(bar='2', foo='b')

In [9]: c2.save()

In [10]: len(Parent.objects.all())
Out[10]: 4

In [11]: len([p for p in Parent.objects.all() if type(p) is Parent])
Out[11]: 4

In [12]: len(Child.objects.all())
Out[12]: 2
```

Comment: Well I'm using inheritance to avoid having to duplicate some properties. For example Child has basically everything in common with Parent except a "parent" property... inheritance seamed like the shortcut, but clearly not.

Your point about if type(p) is Parent not working is true, that probably doesn't work, but is there any reason you couldn't say

if type(p) != Child ???

Comment: That's not going to work, either. All objects in Parent.objects.all() are of type Parent, Django doesn't cast them to the appropriate subclass (see this lengthy discussion between a couple of Django core developers: http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/7d40ad373ebfa912/a20fabc661b7035d)

You can, however, achieve what you want with two queries: Parent.objects.exclude(id__in=[c.id for c in Child.objects.all()])

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` method is essentially about building the WHERE clause in the SQL query, and that's a realy awkward place to be quibbling about exact types. What about, instead...:

```
(p for Parent.objects.all() if type(p) is Parent)
```

this is an iterable (use `[ ]` on the outside instead of `( )` if you want a list instead) for all objects that are *exactly* of type Parent - no subclasses allowed.

Comment: I didn't know this was possible. Interesting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is NOT possible. All objects returned by `Parent.objects.all()` will have a type of `Parent` ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#querysets-still-return-the-model-that-was-requested)), so this answers is unfortunately completely useless.